# Perl Win32::OLE Word Cell Text

Tags: perl

Text is getting truncated.  I have coded the cell range and text option as documented, but the first character of each cell is truncated and only the very last sentence of each cell is printed.  Not sure if this has anything to do with cell formatting, but some of the cells have right alignment.

Any help would be great...here is the code

```
use warnings;  
use strict;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
my $txt = "";
my $var1 = Win32::OLE::Variant->new(VT_BOOL, 'true');

# we are going be working with MS Word Objects
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3; 

# get already active Excel application or open new
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 'Quit');  

# open Excel file
my $Book = $Word->Documents-    >Open("http://classroom.kleinisd.net/webs/lbalthazar/upload/2nd_six_weeks_calendar.docx"); 

#$Word->{Visible}= 0; # we don't need to see Word in an active window

# get the first table
my $table = $Word->ActiveDocument->Tables(1);
foreach my $row (1..4)
{
foreach my $col (1..5)
 {
$txt = $table->Cell($row,$col)->Range->{Text};
print "$txt \n";
}
}
print "Closing document and Word\n";
#$Word->ActiveDocument->Close();
$Word->Quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with visible=1? I remember facing issues with ole objects with visible = 0.